# Why only does Maven Azure DevOps Artifacts only store dependencies from Maven Central? (MuleSoft)

Tags: azure, maven, azure-pipelines, mulesoft, artifacts

I have configured Azure DevOps Maven task to connect to an Artifacts feed to store the artifacts and dependencies, but I only see the Maven Central dependencies, none of the others are stored.

Here is the MuleSoft pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>poc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>

    <name>poc</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <app.runtime>4.3.0</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.3.5</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client-all</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.19</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-apikit-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.13</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-jms-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>azure-maven</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/therevillsgames/therevillsgames/_packaging/azure-maven/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>azure-maven</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/therevillsgames/therevillsgames/_packaging/azure-maven/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>

          <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v2</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

The artifacts are stored in Azure Artifacts, but as shown only from Maven Central and we need the other there too:

[image]

Is there a way to get the MuleSoft dependencies stored too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In azure devops Artifacts, there are only four public upstream sources: npmjs.com, NuGet.org, Maven Central and PyPI, that's why the dependencies from MuleSoft are not stored.

And as of this time, however, custom upstream sources are only available for npm.

You can click [this docuement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops) for detailed information.

Comment: Thanks Jane, that's a shame it would be great to be able to select your own upstream sources like in JFrog...

Answer (score 0):

As said in Azure Devops Artifacts there are only four public upstream sources.
But you can add a cache for the others.

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#maven